# Why TensorBoard summary is not updating?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

I use tensorboard with pytorch1.1 to log loss values.

I use `writer.add_scalar("loss", loss.item(), global_step)` in every for- loop body.

However, the plotting graph does not update while the training is processing.

Every time I want to see the latest loss, I have to restart the tensorboard server.

The code is here

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

# Writer will output to ./runs/ directory by default
writer = SummaryWriter()

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))]
)
trainset = datasets.MNIST("mnist_train", train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(False)
# Have ResNet model take in grayscale rather than RGB
model.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
model.fc = nn.Linear(2048, 10, True)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

epochs = 100

opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

niter = 0

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for step, (x, y) in enumerate(trainloader):
        yp = model(x)
        loss = criterion(yp, y)
        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
        writer.add_scalar("loss", loss.item(), niter)
        niter += 1
        print(loss.item())

grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(images)
writer.add_image("images", grid, 0)
writer.add_graph(model, images)
writer.close()
```

The training is still going on, and the global steps has already been 3594. However, the tensorboard still shows around 1900.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Also for those who have multiple event log files for a single run, you need to start your tensorboard with `--reload_multifile True`

Answer (score 7):

There is caching done internally on the logging side. To see if that is the issue, create your SummaryWriter with

```
writer = SummaryWriter(flush_secs=1)
```

and see if things update right away. If so, feel free to tune flush_secs (defaults to 120) for your case. From your description, though, this might be from the TensorBoard visualization side. If so, it must have something to do with the polling interval.

Does installing TensorFlow (which forces TensorBoard to use a different filesystem backend) change this behavior for you?

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I've solved this problem by downgrade tensorboard from 1.14.0 to 1.13.1.